# Rails 2.3.8 mail NoMethod error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I created a simple post controller with scaffolding and I want send a mail if someone visiting the index page.
I generated a TestMail class:

```
class TestMail < ActionMailer::Base

 def welcome_email(sent_on)
    recipients    'lorem@ipsum.sa'
    from          "My Awesome Site Notifications <notifications@example.com>"
    subject       "Welcome to My Awesome Site"
    sent_on       Time.now

  end

end
```

But if I call this method in Post controller

```
asd=TestMail.welcome_email(Time.now)
```

I got NoMethod error:

```
NoMethodError in PostsController#index

undefined method `welcome_email' for TestMail:Class
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the Rails 3 syntax.
With Rails 2.3, you need to use `deliver_` or `create_`.

```
# creates and delivers the email
TestMail.deliver_welcome_email(Time.now)

# creates the email
email = TestMail.create_welcome_email(Time.now)
```